# Opacity input form screw up my placeholder color

Tags: css, html, forms, opacity

I would like to make a simple form where the input is transparent, but when I set the opacity of the input, the placeholder text is ALSO "opacified". How could I get rid of it? I want my placeholder text to be plain white.

I know it seems like a dummie issue but I search multiple times without finding solution...

The graphic final desire: http://cl.ly/image/1W0q1R0X2n0m/Image%202014-05-15%20at%2012.15.06%20PM.png

***JSFIDDLE***: http://jsfiddle.net/v35kJ/

**HTML**

```
<form action="formulaire.php" method="get">
<label for="email"><img id="fleche" src="img/fleche.png" alt=""></label>
<div id="mail">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Entrez votre e-mail" required>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Restons en contact">
</div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#mail #email{
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.2;
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: HNThin;
padding-left: 10px;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a rgba (red, green, blue, alpha) value for the background, where the last value is opacity.

e.g. `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);`

### [Revised Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/v35kJ/1/)

CSS

```
#mail #email{
   height: 30px;
   width: 200px;
   opacity: 0.2;
   background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: HNThin;
   padding-left: 10px;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
   margin: 0;
}
```

By setting `opacity` on an element, it, any children or related rendered items (such as text etc) will be subject to it. `rgba` values let you target specific CSS properties with opacity levels (so long as they allow for color setting)

Answer (score 0):

Once use this css for Firefox

```
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: black;
}
```

now find out for other browsers.